# Why am I getting this syntax error in SQLITE3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to save two `lists` into my *sqlite3* database. This is my code:

```
import sqlite

con=sqlite3.connect('output.db')        
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS output(name VARCHAR(10),content VARCHAR(30))')
for i in range(len(X)):
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO output(X,VALUES(?))',(X[i]))
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO output(Y,VALUES(?))',(Y[i]))
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

I have two lists called `X=['abc','def']` and `Y=['ghi','jkl']`. But every time I run this code, I get an `OperationalError` saying:

```
OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error
```

Please help me. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT` command is

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

So it should be

```
query = 'INSERT INTO output (name, content) VALUES(?, ?)'

for i in range(len(X)):
    cur.execute(query, ('X', X[i]))
    cur.execute(query, ('Y', Y[i]))
```

For more robust solution you can use `dict`

```
data = {'X': X, 'Y': Y}

for key, values in data.items():
    for value in values:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO output (name, content) VALUES(?, ?)', (key, value))
```

Comment: what is the second bracket  in `VALUES(?,?))` for?

Comment: @Abhishek There is only 1 `VALUES(?, ?)`

Comment: Now I'm getting an error `TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: @Abhishek Where?

Comment: @Abhishek Try `cur.execute(query, ('X', X[i]))`